# Generar códigos de caracteres aleatorios en campo "Subtítulo"

Tags: wordpress

Nos gustaría poder incluir un campo de subtítulo a Wordpress (cosa que haremos con un Plugin) y que dicho campo genere automáticamente una serie de, no sé, 6 caracteres aleatorios como "AXTWEV" por defecto en cada post.

[image: Ejemplo]

¿Alguien sabe cómo podríamos lograr eso?

Comment: Cual es la duda, ¿generar caracteres o insertar el campo?

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución es utilizar este plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-subtitle/

Y modificarlo para que cuando haga el render del cuadro de texto presente los caracteres aleatorios:

Para generar los caracteres pueden usar esta funcion:

```
<?php
function generarCodigo($longitud) {
 $key = '';
 $pattern = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
 $max = strlen($pattern)-1;
 for($i=0;$i < $longitud;$i++) $key .= $pattern{mt_rand(0,$max)};
 return $key;
}

//Ejemplo de uso

echo generarCodigo(6); // genera un código de 6 caracteres de longitud.
?>
```